# How to add different timers for specific images?

Tags: javascript

I've been working on this traffic light code for a few weeks now and I have finally made it work automatically with a set timer. However, now I want to make it more realistic by giving each image in my array a specific time so e.g. green light is viewed for 5 seconds, yellow for 3 and so on.

Current code:

```js
var list = ["only red1.jpg","red-yellow 2.jpg", "green3.jpg","yellowonly4.jpg"];
    var nextlight = 0;
    var timer;
    function ChangeLight() {
      nextlight = nextlight + 1;      
      if (nextlight == list.length) 
        nextlight = 0;      
      var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');     
      firstlight.src = list[nextlight]; 
    } 


     timer = setInterval(ChangeLight,1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  
  
  <h1>JavaScript Code</h1> 
  <p>Traffic Light</p> 
  
<img id="traffic" src="only red1.jpg">
  <button type="button" onclick="ChangeLight()">Change Light</button>   
</body> 
</html>
```

I'm a javascript newbie so please no over complicated code and thank you for any help.

Comment: `var list = [{ img: "only red1.jpg", time: 5000 }, { img: "red-yellow 2.jpg", time: 3000 }, { img: "green3.jpg", time: 5000 }, ... ];`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the data structure, persist delay with image src to set and use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` to schedule the execution on function recursively with delay.

```js
var list = [{
  src: "only red1.jpg",
  interval: 10000
}, {
  src: "red-yellow 2.jpg",
  interval: 5000
}, {
  src: "green3.jpg",
  interval: 3000
}, {
  src: "yellowonly4.jpg",
  interval: 1000
}];

var nextlight = 0;
var timer;

function ChangeLight() {  
  var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');
  var obj = list[nextlight];
  firstlight.src = obj.src;
  firstlight.alt = obj.src;
  timer = setTimeout(ChangeLight, obj.interval);
  nextlight = nextlight + 1;
  if (nextlight == list.length)
    nextlight = 0;
}

ChangeLight();
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Code</h1>
<p>Traffic Light</p>

<img id="traffic" src="only red1.jpg">
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeLight()">Change Light</button>
```

Comment: Better... As usual :)

Comment: thank you very much, I'm just struggling to run this through a text file then saving it as a html , where shall I put the script tag?

Comment: I've made it work however it only starts when I click the button, I want it to start automatically.

Comment: @Satpal Bro I'm sorry for being a pain, it works great, thank you. I am still learning Javascript and I am just curious what does these 3 lines do? And why did you execute the function ChangeLight at the end?             (var obj = list[nextlight];
               firstlight.src = obj.src;
               firstlight.alt = obj.src;)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your lights to `objects`, and include a timer in them.

```js
var list = [
  {
    img: "only red1.jpg", 
    timer: 1000
  },
  {
    img: "red-yellow 2.jpg", 
    timer: 2000
  },
  {
    img: "green3.jpg", 
    timer: 3000
  },
  {
    img: "yellowonly4.jpg", 
    timer: 4000
  }
];

var nextlight = 0;
var timer;

function ChangeLight() {
  nextlight = nextlight + 1;
  if (nextlight == list.length)
    nextlight = 0;
  var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');
  var light = list[nextlight];
  console.log(light.img + ' lit for ' + light.timer + ' ms');
  setTimeout(ChangeLight, light.timer);
  //firstlight.src = list[nextlight];
}

ChangeLight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and in handler function, change the value of `duration` based on current signal

```js
var list = ["only red1.jpg", "red-yellow 2.jpg", "green3.jpg", "yellowonly4.jpg"];
var nextlight = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById('result');

function ChangeLight() {
  nextlight = nextlight + 1;
  if (nextlight == list.length)
    nextlight = 0;
  var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');
  firstlight.src = list[nextlight];
  elem.textContent = list[nextlight];
  var setTimeoutDuration = 0;
  if (list[nextlight].indexOf('green') > -1) {
    setTimeoutDuration = 5;
  } else if (list[nextlight].indexOf('yellow') > -1) {
    setTimeoutDuration = 3;
  } else if (list[nextlight].indexOf('red') > -1) {
    setTimeoutDuration = 2;
  } else {
    setTimeoutDuration = 1;
  }
  setTimeout(ChangeLight, setTimeoutDuration * 1000);
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Code</h1>
<p>Traffic Light</p>

<img id="traffic" src="only red1.jpg">
<div id="result"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeLight()">Change Light</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the array a 2D with filename and time duration. 
In the function, use `setTimeout` to invoke itself in the time duration taken from the array.

Check the code. (Set an ALT attribute to show you the change).

```js
var list = [["only red1.jpg",3],["red-yellow 2.jpg",4],[ "green3.jpg",5],["yellowonly4.jpg",6]];
    var nextlight = 0;
    var timer;
    function ChangeLight() {
      nextlight = nextlight + 1;      
      if (nextlight == list.length) 
        nextlight = 0;      
      var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');     
      firstlight.src = list[nextlight][0]; 
      firstlight.setAttribute('alt',list[nextlight][0]);
      setTimeout(ChangeLight,list[nextlight][1]*1000);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  
  
  <h1>JavaScript Code</h1> 
  <p>Traffic Light</p> 
  
<img id="traffic" src="only red1.jpg">
  <button type="button" onclick="ChangeLight()">Change Light</button>   
</body> 
</html>
```